# Insert an ID into $this->request->data array before saving in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a contact form which asks users for their name, email address and message.

The name and email address are stored in `Person` and the message is stored in `Message`

`Message` belongs to `Person` so when I do:

`$this->Person->Message->saveAll($this->request->data)`

..the name and email address are INSERTED in the `people` table and the message is INSERTED in the `messages` table with a `person_id`.

So far, so good.

Now, what I want to do is provide a way for `Person` to be UPDATED and `Message` to be INSERTED if the user (identified by their email address) comes back and submits a second message.

The only way I have found to do this is to run find on `Person` to see if there's a record containing the email address submitted in the form. If there is, I use `array_merge` to add it to `$this->request->data['Person']`. This works, but this feels like a bit of a hackish way of doing things.

Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding your Person, you could just set person_id of your Message und just run save on it, so you don't have to save the person again.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would also work...  but my question is still the same, how do I set the ID without doing something messy like array_merge?

Comment: `$this->Message->create(); $this->Message->set($this->request->data); $this->Message->set('person_id', $person_id);`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the beforeSave() method of the Person Model.

```
# App/Model/Person.php

function beforeSave()
{
   if(empty($this->data['Person']['id'])
   {
     $person = $this->findByEmail($this->data['Person']['email']);

     if(!empty($person))
     {
         $this->data['Person']['id'] = $person['Person']['id'];
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: this almost works but Cake tries to do an INSERT with the Person.id instead of an UPDATE. Obviously the INSERT fails because Person.id is the primary key.